# How to express "x out of y"?

Tags: translation

The phrase I'm trying to grab is usually used when stating survey results or something of the like, e.g.:

> A survey found that 7 out of 10 men go to the gym every week.

Could this be translated as something like this?

> 一个概观发现，七个出十个男人每周去健身房`

Comment: one possibility：x ＜量词＞ 中 y，e。g。７个中１０个男人  (study dictionaries and sentence warehouses)

Comment: 调查发现，十个男人之中有七个每周都去健身房。
Or less verbose: 调查发现，70%的男人每周都去健身房。

Comment: regarding comment #2: dummy verb 有 seems necessary，see previous discussions of this point，again quoting CCG: "有 is used as a dummy verb when an indefinitely referenced noun is moved to a subject, that is, pre-verbal position", thus x ＜量词＞ 中有 y ＜量词＞ seems possible, 
need for 有 confirmed by web search for 个中有：他会随意决定你在5个中会有多少遭到破坏。（jukuu）几乎十个中学生中就有八个是近视眼.（iciba）三个中有两个有点小难度（http://www.gxdxw.cn/jdnjjzw/sgzylgydxnd_609.html）之
possibly not needed

Comment: Specifically, a very native translation for "x out of ten" is "x成": 一个调查发现**七成**男人每周都去健身房。

Comment: You may also say it in fraction in Chinese style: **十分之七**的男人每周去健身房, **十分之七** in Chinese equals to **seven tenths** in English.

Comment: Actually it is not necessary to translate the article "**a**" in Chinese: 调查发现, 七成的男人每周去健身房.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to express a percentage:

> （某集体之中）有十分之七的人去了健身房。
>
> 或者：（平均下来）十个人里面有七个去了健身房。
>
> 70% of them went to the gym.

If you want to express a number:

> **这**十个人里面有七个去了健身房。
>
> (There are exactly 10 people in total, and exactly 7 people went to the gym.)

Answer (score 1):

No. It should be something like this:

一項調查顯示, 十個男人中有七個每週上健身房。